# PHP AMI Connection - saving incoming and outgoing calls to a database is not working

Tags: php, sockets, voip, asterisk, amazon-ami

Using the AMI (API connection with an Asteriskserver so I can use a PHP Socket connection) I'm trying to catch the recieving data using PHP in a way that I can record outgoing and incomming calls for the CRM system (webbased) used at the company I work for.
But I'm not getting the result I am hoping for...
The full code can be found on PasteBin http://pastebin.com/AwRNBW2G

I catch the outgoing calls this way, and that works:

```
  if($givenkey = array_search("Context: from-internal", $content)){
            $calleridKey = $givenkey + 1;
            $idSIP = $givenkey - 1;
            $dialNumber = str_replace("Extension: 0","31",$content[$calleridKey]);
            $dialNumber = str_replace("Extension: ", "", $dialNumber);
            $fromSIP = str_replace("Channel: SIP/", "", $content[$idSIP]);
            $fromSIP = substr($fromSIP, 0, 2);
            $dialTime = date('r');

            $uitgaand = array(
                            "Phonenumber"   => $dialNumber,
                            "Type"          => "Uitgaand",
                            "datetime"      => $dialTime,
                            "SIP"           => $fromSIP
                            );
```

The incomming calls are being catched this way, but that's not working properly:

```
   if($givenkey = array_search("AppData: Using CallerID ", $content)){
            if(array_search("Channel: SIP/31000000000", $content)+5 == $InCallKey = array_search("AppData: Using CallerID", $content)){
                    $calleridNum = explode('"',str_replace('AppData: Using CallerID "',"",$content[$InCallKey]));
                    $pickupSource = array_search("Source: SIP/31000000000", $content);
                    if($pickupSource+1 == $pickupKey = array_search("Destination: SIP/", $content)){
                            $pickupBy =  str_replace("Destination: SIP/","",$content[$pickupkey]);
                            $pickupBy = substr($pickupBy, 0, 2);
                            $dialTime = date('r');         
                            $inkomend = array(
                                            "Phonenumber" => $calleridNum[0],
                                            "Type"          => "Binnenkomend",
                                            "datetime"      => $dialTime,
                                            "SIP"           => $pickupBy
                                            );
```

I have the array that I make not available right now but, if necessary, I can save the array and post it here with personal data filtered.

I know that the code I'm using right now is not neat, but I wrote it with the goal: quick result. If I have a working code I will optimize it and clean it up. Tips about this are also very welcome. It's too bad that I cannot find any good documentation about this so I have to start from the beginning and could only find the working class that I'm using right now, however it's not very complete.
I had to write this part without any knowledge about VOIP or AMI or Asterisk.

To be short, here are my questions:
- How can I record incoming and outgoing calls to eventually save them in a database by using the AMI?
- How can I keep alive the connection with the server the best way? The method I'm using now is not optimal as the connection fails atleast once within 48 hours.
- Do you have tips or suggestions about optimizing the code and neater code-writing? And do you maybe know any functions that I could use instead of a function that I am using?

With regards,
Dempsey

> Since recently I get this error which
>   I cannot solve properly. This error
>   creates itself after about 15 minutes
>   running. It would run atleast 24 hours
>   before:
>
> ```
> PHP Notice:  fwrite(): send of 16 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe in /var/www/html/phpami/AMILoader.php on line 147
> Net_AsteriskManagerException: Authorisation failed in /var/www/html/phpami/AMILoader.php on line 173
> #0 /var/www/html/phpami/AMILoader.php(173): Net_AsteriskManager-login('GEBRUIKERSNAAM','WACHTWOORD')
> #1 /var/www/html/phpami/AMILoader.php(306): Net_AsteriskManager-_sendCommand('Action: Ping???...')
> #2 /var/www/html/phpami/AMILoader.php(543): Net_AsteriskManager->ping()
> #3 {main}
> ```
>
> Can anyone help me with this too? The
>   authorisation data is correct (it is
>   using the same data in the whole
>   script and it does get a connection).
>   Also I don't get the response 'Action:
>   Ping???...' which it says is being
>   send by the script as command, but
>   where do the three questionmarks and
>   periods come from?

Answer (score 1):

this framework should be handy:
https://github.com/marcelog/PAMI

otherwise you can check vTiger sources and how it handles ami integration:
http://www.vtiger.com/index.php?Itemid=57&id=30&option=com_content&task=view

Answer (score 1):

If your using php, one of the easiest way to connect to the AMI is using the php-astmanager class. It supports callback on certain "events" so that you can catch the data you need. The best (only?) maintained copy is part of [FreePBX](http://www.freepbx.org) and can be pulled right out of the latest version (2.9 as of this writing).

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. I will certainly look into this and come back here to share my findings.